# Remove specific characters from rows in specific column

Tags: python, lambda, str-replace

This is beginner's question.
I've tried to remove hyphens and the first two characters of the personalnumbers in the personalnumber column. The hyphens are still there in my df and I get an error message for the replace I'm trying to do with regex (see picture).

It's a 12 numbered personal numbers where I want to remove the '19' of the years.

I was  thinking that it might be because my dtype is object and I tried to change it to string but that doesn't apply either - even if I dont get an syntax error, just like in hyphens case. To change objects to strings I used:

```
app_df_new.astype({'personalnumber': str}).dtypes
```

[image]

And when I add the missing '\ to in the regex it gives me this error message:

[image]

Comment: It isn't very helpful when you talk about data you blurred

Comment: Sorry, it's because it SSN's. But what matters is that one of the personalnumbers format wich is: YYMMDD-XXXX. And I'm trying to get rid of the hyphens in [70]. 

In the rest of the dataset the format is rather YYYYMMDDXXXX and in [71] i'm trying to get rid of the first two characters. The result would then be YYMMDDXXXX.

Comment: You could have shown example data man

Comment: Learnt my lesson! :)

Comment: If you feel my answer helped, you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error probably due to a missing single quote `'` for the regex expression.

You are missing a `'` quote before the closing bracket.

`app_df_new['personalnumber'] = app_df_new['personalnumber'].str.replace(r'\^.{1,2}')`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a single quote:

```
app_df_new['personalnumber'] = app_df_new['personalnumber'].str.replace(r'\^.{1,2}','')
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I got this error message when I fixed  that. Not sure if I understand it. Is it that it doesn't understand my regex: TypeError: replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'repl' ?

Comment: What error message? That error message was because you missed a ' in your expression

Comment: I added another picture. The first error message was "EOL while scanning string literal". When I added the r'\ it gave me the message "replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'repl'"

Comment: @SevgiCamuz Replace takes two arguments, I changed my answer now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Weirdly I don't make either the replace or the lstrip to "stick" to my df. Do you have any idea if it could be because it's objects and not strings.? I also tried:
app_df_new = app_df_new['personalnumber'] = app_df_new.personalnumber[2:]. That didn't work either